# How to use a helper library in my Android project

Tags: android, api

I'm fairly new to Android development. I'm trying to make an app using the Star Wars API (SWAPI). There is a helper [library](https://github.com/Oleur/SWAPI-Android-SDK)

I cloned this project but am not sure how to use it. I created a MainActivity but can't reference any of the classes (from the helper library) in my MainActivity class. Do I have to add anything to my gradle.build file?

Comment: did you add your library in libs folder?

Comment: @BalaRaja Do I need to make a new project or can I edit the one I cloned?

Comment: did you add jar file in libs folder?

Comment: @BalaRaja No. I'm not sure where to get the jar file from.

Comment: Try here https://jitpack.io/#Oleur/SWAPI-Android-SDK

Comment: @cricket_007 That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Download the library first. Extract it.
In Android studio:
Goto File->Project Structure->Click on the green + button-> import gradle project(Since the SDK has gradle files)->Next->Select the downloaded SDK folder.->Finish.

After the gradle files sync up. Goto File->Project structure(The added sdk folder should be visible in the left side now)->Click on the "app" folder in the left side.->Click on the "Dependencies" tab.->Click on the green + button on the right side->Module dependency->Select the module(Your SWAPI sdk folder).

The project syncs one more time and you are done.